# Reading distant txt file android

Tags: java, android, url

I have this code to read the last line of a distant txt file :

```
 try {
        URL url = new URL("http://intram.cluny.ensam.fr/meteo/downld02.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        while(str != null) {
           ligne=str;
           str = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

This code is working very fine on my LG Optimus L3 (Android 2.3.6) but crashes at start on my Nexus 7 (Android 4.2.1). Why ? How to fix it ?

EDIT:
Thanks for your answers

I don't know what is logcat stack trace, but I think it's the following, tell me if I'm wrong

```
12-31 18:54:07.469: W/ActivityThread(29021): Application fr.ensam.cluny can be debugged on port 8100...
12-31 18:54:07.969: D/AndroidRuntime(29021): Shutting down VM
12-31 18:54:07.969: W/dalvikvm(29021): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f6c930)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.ensam.cluny/fr.ensam.cluny.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:282)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at fr.ensam.cluny.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
12-31 18:54:07.969: E/AndroidRuntime(29021):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post log cat stack trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've refrained from giving us a stack trace, I'm giving this answer with a bit of guessing.

My guess is you're getting a [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This exception occurs on Android 3.0 and above, when you try to use the network on the main UI thread. This also explains why you don't see the exception on Gingerbread (Android 2.3).

To fix this, move all networking code into a [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).